# Pressing down arrow jumps to top of Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Problem**

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is locked except for some cells where I want a user to enter text. Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> jumps to the next unlocked cell just fine in most cases except for in one case where, after pressing enter, the selected cell jumps to the top of the sheet instead of selecting the cell just below.

**Useful Tidbits**

- I have a bunch of named ranges (don't know if that's relevant)
- The problem does not span across a page break.
- The problem occurs every time I lock the sheet and try to tab/arrow key/enter from row 41 to 42. It's almost as if there is a hidden page break there!
- It always jumps to the topmost unlocked cell.

Comment: @JMK Ok. Is there a way to migrate it to SuperUser?

Comment: @Senoculus: you don't have to worry about it. Users with 5k+ reputation can vote to migrate your question (or a mod with a diamond in his/her name can do it right away). Your question might move at a time or another to superuser, this is *normal*

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem before. Does this happen to be the last unlocked row with data ?

If that's the case, then here's what I noticed : it seems that when limiting users to unlocked cells, Excel will also create a "box" with corners being the last rows and columns where data exists. This is not the best explanation, but see on my question if that better answers your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748263/locking-cells-for-selection-wrong-behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would be ok with excel jumping to the top once it got to the bottom of the sheet, but it is jumping prematurely. For example: In the link you posted, you have 3 sections (A and D are unlocked, and section C is locked). The behavior I am experiencing is that using the keyboard arrows, the selected cell would cycle through all unlocked cells in section A, and then instead of jumping over section C to section D, it would start back at the beginning of section A. The only way to get to section D is to use the mouse and click.